# How to execute a script on server from client side?

Tags: linux, shell, client-server, pipe, popen

I have a shell script placed at the root of  a linux machine which acts as a server.I want to execute that script from client side

could popen be used to achieve this or any other alternative approaches available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 "( cd /var && chmod +x my_script.sh && ./my_script)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ssh (server) (script/command to be run with path)" from your client machine.